# Import Python packages across Windows and Linux using .pth file

Tags: python, linux, python-import, arcgis, pythonpath

I'm using [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS) that is built for Windows with no version for Linux. They have dedicated Python library called ArcPy, that has scripts of all of the tools available in this software.

On Ubuntu 16.04 I'm trying to import this package to my Python, so I can use all those scripts. Inside `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` I created `Desktop.pth` into which I echoed:

```
/media/adam/somedisk/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.5/bin
/media/adam/somedisk/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.5/arcpy
/media/adam/somedisk/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.5/ArcToolBox/Scripts
```

Now entering Python shell and typing `import arcpy` returns `ImportError: No module named arcpy`. I know I typed the paths with correct escaping, because I can `cd` them.

Is it a correct way of importing Python packages across OSs? What went wrong here?

Comment: ArcPy relies on Windows binaries (and also does license checks), to get it to work it's probably a lot more work than just transferring the Python libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can not use arcpy unless, either ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS engine is installed in the machine. ArcPy does not work without the binaries.